# address power of polynomial overflow via FFT

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I'm interested in all the n-th elementary symmetric polynomials coefficients of some coefficients, and using the FFT approach leads to some strange overflow issue, wondering how can I address them.

The interested polynomail:$f(x) = (1+ax)^n$, I am using $a=1$ and $n=100$ for example. And i was using two different approach.

The correct but not efficient one: `reduce(numpy.polymul, [[1, 1] for _ in range(100)])`

and the `"efficient"` but `incorrect` one: `numpy.fft.irfft(numpy.prod([numpy.fft.rfft([1, 1]+[0 for _ in range(98)]) for _ in range(100)], axis=0))[:101]`

But if i reduce the $n$ to $3$, then both approaches would have the same result.

I have tested the range of $n$ to have both approaches match, which is around $34$, for $2 \leq n \leq 33$, both approaches would have the same result.

Wondering what's off for the second efficient approach.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't think using `for` loop would address any issue here, essentially what I'm interested in is why bulk FFT transform all the coefficient into the frequency domain and bulk pointwise product would result in overflow issues

Comment: Plot the result for $n\in 1\ldots 100$ and find when it starts failing.

Comment: fails at $n=34$. updated the description :)